# Android Studio: Can't get return string from another class

Tags: java, android

I know it's kind of stupid question, but it's been a long time since I programmed Java in Android Studio. So actually I have the problem that I can't get a return from a class to another. I tried different kind of solutions suggested here, but none of them worked. Not sure why. I'm getting nothing displayed TextView in xml.

Here is the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView txt_temp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    XMLreference();
    StringRequest();
}

public void XMLreference(){
    txt_temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_temp);
}

public void StringRequest(){
    WebServiceRequest webService = new WebServiceRequest();
    String request = webService.main();

    txt_temp.setText(request);
}
```

}

And here is the WebServiceRequest.java:

```
public class WebServiceRequest {
    private static final String username = "*********"; // put your Device Cloud username here
    private static final String password = "*********"; // put your Device Cloud password here
    public String responseContent;

    /**
     * Run the web service request
     */
    public String main() {
        HttpsURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            // Create url to the Device Cloud server for a given web service request
            URL url = new URL("https://devicecloud.digi.com/ws/DataStream/00000000-00000000-********-********/xbee.serialIn");
            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // Build authentication string
            String userpassword = username + ":" + password;

            // can change this to use a different base64 encoder
            String encodedAuthorization = Base64.encodeToString(userpassword.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT).trim();

            // set request headers
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
                    + encodedAuthorization);

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            Scanner isScanner = new Scanner(is);
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            while (isScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                buf.append(isScanner.nextLine() + "\n");
            }
            responseContent = buf.toString();

            // add line returns between tags to make it a bit more readable
            responseContent = responseContent.replaceAll("><", ">\n<");

            // Output response to standard out
            // System.out.println(responseContent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Print any exceptions that occur
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.disconnect();
        }
        return responseContent;
    }
}
```

I already tried to create

```
public void getResponseContent() {
    return responseContent;
}
```

And getting it with

```
WebServiceRequest webService = new WebServiceRequest();
String request = webService.getResponsteContent();
```

But it didn't work either. I'm not sure but I'm making somewhere a stupid mistake and after hours of programming I can't find the clue to solve it.

Comment: Rename `main()` to `getResponsteContent()`

Comment: @MuratK. sorry but it didn't work either. Do you mean like this?  public void StringRequest(){ WebServiceRequest webService = new WebServiceRequest(); String request = webService.getResponseContent(); txt_temp.setText(request); }

Comment: Are you sure `responseContent` was not empty, i.e. the web service call was successful?

Comment: I have the feeling, the problem is the try/catch function. Even if I create a string "Hello World" and try to return it, I get an empty line.
The code should work, it was an export from digi device. The only thing I change was Baser64 encoding. Before it was `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;` and `String encodedAuthorization = Base64.encodeBase64String(userpassword.getBytes()).trim();`. But android studio didn't recognize it, so I changed the lines. I tried the export with Python and it did worked without any problems. Or maybe the Base64 encouding is creating a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am not so sure if you want to have a constructor, but the `main()` never gets called so `responseContent` is always empty.

To match your code snipped

```
WebServiceRequest webService = new WebServiceRequest();
String request = webService.getResponsteContent();
```

Change your method `main` in `WebServiceRequest` to a constructor like this

```
public WebServiceRequest() { .. } // it was String main() before
```

It will get called as soon as you instantiate a `WebServiceRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Web requests must be done from a second thread.

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //your main method here
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            //update your textView here
                    }

                });

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(run);
    thread.start();
```

Also, you need to move the response code and update to the textView inside your web request method. Changes to the user interface must be posted to a handler.

Another option is to make your class extend IntentService. See here if you want to check that out.

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html